Trying to find the `recommended dns` data for GCP Cloud SQL instance
I'm working through the documentation for connecting to a private Cloud SQL instance. I created the instance with a private IP (no public access), set up cloud sql proxy on my local, and am able to connect to the network successfully. However, I see in the docs that the console does not automatically add the required private dns records to go from the proxy to the db instance.
When I run this with my sql instance, I do not see the mentioned recommended dns record in the result like the documentation claims exists.
gcloud sql instances describe INSTANCE_NAME \
--project=PROJECT_ID

I do get all the other configuration data, but nothing that matches the suggested dns format:
INSTANCE_UID.PROJECT_DNS_LABEL.REGION_NAME.sql.goog.
My instance is a second gen, so I don't know if that has something to do with it. I'd like to get this working via the console before I seek to automate it with Terraform, e.g. I plan on automating this later, but that is not my current goal.

I tried to reproduce the issue at my end. At first I also have created the instance from the console by selecting only private IP as network as shown below

I am also unable to see cloud DNS names. It seems like this is expected behavior when an instance is created from the console. As you can observe in the above screenshot,cloud SQL launches instances in PSA(Private Service Access) with Private IP as an option. However to have a cloud DNS name, Instance should be launched in PSC(Private Service Connect) mode and as per doc Create a Cloud SQL instance launching cloudSQL in PSC is not available via console.
To cross verify this,I have launched the instance with --enable-private-service-connect option as stated in above doc, Then I am able to see DNS name with pattern INSTANCE\\\_UID.PROJECT\\\_DNS\\\_LABEL.REGION\\\_NAME.sql.goog. in both console and gcloud sql instances describe  command output.
This confirms to me that, To have a DNS name instance should be launched in PSC.
Please go through DNS names and records and  PSC blog to have a better understanding of DNS and Private Service Connect.

Thanks for verifying that. I'm not a fan of things being different between the console and the CLI-- AWS seems to be leagues ahead in this regard.

I'm using Cloud Run, and I ultimately found some documentation. I can use the instance name without having to set up a dns record or Private Service Connect.
There were 3 main things I had to do:

I set the host to use unix sockets: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME, which does come back from that describe call. node postgres automatically adds the /.s.PGSQL.5432 bit to the end. node postgres allows this to be set on the same host connection property, so I didn't have to change the code for that.
Disable ssl in the node postgres setup. I still have it required on the Cloud Sql instance, but step 3 requires no ssl on the connection setup.
In my Cloud Run service, I clicked Edit & Deploy a new Revision. Scroll down toward the bottom and there's a section for Cloud SQL Connections. Click Add Connection and you can choose the instance you want to allow. This step allows the service to connect to the database instance without all the other setups like vpc peering, etc.


SSL can be required on the database instance, but it needs to be disabled in the Cloud Run application's connection config because step 3 above uses the Cloud SQL Proxy. This automatically uses SSL/TLS to connect to the server, so enabling ssl in the app's connection config causes issues here.

Other things that may have affected this, but I haven't yet undone these to see if they were needed.:

enable the Cloud SQL Admin API.
use a public IP. You still need to use the Cloud SQL Proxy or other verified networks to access the db.
enable private service for the network that the database is using. VPC -> select the VPC; click the Private Services Access tab and then `Private Connections to services. Then enable it.

